# Using If-Statement as test condition for For-Loop in Vb.net

Tags: java, vb.net, for-loop, if-statement

I've been writing some software in Vb.net and I've come to a point in the program where it would be best if I could place an if-statement in the header of a for-loop.

For example, in java, I could achieve what I need like so..

```
for (int I = 0; myArray[I].compareTo("") == 0; I ++)
{
    'code here
}
```

Unfortunately in Vb.net, all I know how to do is increment one number to a given number in a for-loop.  I am aware however, that what I need to do can be accomplished using an if-test inside the for-loop

```
For I as Integer = 0 To myArray.length 'only possible test is comparison between two ints

    'code here
    If myArray(I).compareTo("") <> 0 Then
       Exit For
    End If

Next
```

Its not a big deal having to do this but if there is a way to streamline this more into the for-loop control then I would like to know for now and future reference.

So my question is, is it possible to check an if-condition (other than comparing two numbers) inside the header of a for-loop in Vb.net?

**Update:** In response to @Olivier Jacot-Descombes 's answer, I just wanted to clarify that I know while loops are used to test if-conditions in loops, but they lose the functionality of auto-incrementing possessed by for-loops.  In Java, for-loops can do both of these.  Which is why I'm wondering if Vb.net has the same functionality all within the header of a for-loop control somehow.

Comment: In VB, For / Next loops are designed to go from one number, to, another number, where both numbers are known in advance of the loop, and do not change once the loop has started. As Oliver mentioned, another looping construct would be more appropriate here.

Comment: If you want Java's for loop capabilities, use C#. It's much closer to Java than VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. Visual Basic languages don't have anything like the C/java style `for()` loop.

The longer answer is that depending on what you want, you might not even need a loop.

```
Dim a = {"a", Nothing, "", "b"}

' this will print from 0 to 1, but Array.IndexOf returns -1 if value is not found
For i = 0 To Array.IndexOf(a, "") - 1
    Debug.Print(i & "")
Next

For Each item In a : If item = "" Then Exit For ' this is actually 2 lines separated by : 
    Debug.Print("'{0}'", item)
Next

For Each item In a.TakeWhile(Function(s) s > "") ' TakeWhile is a System.Linq extension
    Debug.Print("'{0}'", item)
Next

a.TakeWhile(Function(s) s > "").ToList.ForEach(AddressOf Debug.Print) ' prints a

a.TakeWhile(Function(s) s > "").ToList.ForEach(Sub(s) Debug.Print(s)) ' prints a
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a While-Loop instead

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
While i < myArray.Length AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(myArray(i))
    'Code here
    i += 1
End While
```

In VB a string can be empty (`""`) or `Nothing` (`null` in C#). In order to cope with both situations use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)`.

`AndAlso` (unlike `And`) ensures shortcut evaluation. I.e. if the first condition is not `True` then the second will not be evaluated. We need this here, otherwise the array would throw an "Index out of bounds" exception. Note also that the array index goes from 0 to array.Length - 1.

But you can also exit from a For-loop with `Exit For`

```
For I As Integer = 0 To myArray.Length-1

    'code here
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(myArray(I)) Then
       Exit For
    End If

Next
```

But exiting a loop like this can make the code unreadable. The problem is that the For-loop has now 2 exit points and loop and exit conditions defined at different places.

There is also a [Do...Loop statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) allowing you to test the condition at the end of the loop.

Comment: You may want to mention that bailing out of a `for / next` with `Exit For` is considered bad form, and a code smell, by many people.

Comment: `Exit For`, like its direct counterpart from C#, `break`, is fine and should be used. Also fine would be to use `goto` to emulate reasonable language constructs in case the language misses them (such as emulating `Continue` in VBA). Avoiding language features at all costs just for the sake of it, without considering the rationale, may lead to some inefficient and unreadable code.